# neo4j: how to eliminate subpaths from the result

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

i want to return paths of size 0..4 starting from node a. but i want to return only the longest paths (skip subpaths). For graph:

```
a -> b - > c
|
| -> d
```

i'd like to return only `a -> b -> c` and `a -> d` but not `a` nor `a -> b`

**edit**

it means that if there is a path longer than 4, i still need the longest paths of size 0..4. so for:

```
a -> b -> c -> d -> e -> f
```

i'd like to get `a -> b -> c -> d -> e`

Comment: Instead of the longest path, I think you are searching all the path  between the node A and the leafs of the tree, no ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get all paths up to length 4 that start at a root node and either end at a leaf node or have a length of 4:

```
MATCH path = (a)-[*0..4]->(b)
WHERE NOT ()-->(a) AND (LENGTH(path) = 4 OR NOT (b)-->())
RETURN path;
```

Answer (score 2):

Reproducing with your sample data set:

```
CREATE (a:Node {name:"A"})-[:RELATION]->(b:Node {name:"B"})-[:RELATION]->(c:Node {name:"C"}),
(a)-[:RELATION]->(d:Node {name:"D"})
```

You can restrict the returned paths doing a `WHERE` this way:

```
match path = (a)-[*0..4]->(b)
where not ()-->(a) and not (b)-->()
return path
```

The output will be:

```
╒═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"path"                                                     │
╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│[{"name":"A"},{},{"name":"B"},{"name":"B"},{},{"name":"C"}]│
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│[{"name":"A"},{},{"name":"D"}]                             │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: it doesn't work if path is longer than 4. the restriction `not (b) -> ()` makes it matches only paths ending with leafs